# DT in R, format cell outputs.

Tags: javascript, r, dt

I have data in a long format

```
library(data.table)
library(DT)

my.data.long <- data.table(                  
            date = c("2015-06-31","2016-06-31",
                     "2015-06-31","2016-06-31",
                     "2015-06-31","2016-06-31"),
            variable = c("no.receipts","no.receipts",
                         "sales.dollars","sales.dollars",
                         "customers","customers"),
            value = c(1234,2456,
                        52360.25,101256.36,
                        290,385))
```

I would like to display it in a wide format

```
my.data.to.display <- dcast(my.data.long, variable ~ date, value.var = c("value"))
```

Is there any way to format the output with DT to so the "sales.dollars" can be formatted. At present it is limited to columns. I would like to format rows.

```
datatable(my.data.to.display) %>% formatCurrency("2015-06-31")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like such a row feature isn't available on DT (can be tweaked for formatStyle if css has to be tweaked) . The only viable option (imo) using scales or formatting before widening it.

```
library(scales)


my.data.long$value[my.data.long$variable=='sales.dollars'] <- dollar(my.data.long$value[my.data.long$variable=='sales.dollars'] )

my.data.long$value[my.data.long$variable=='sales.dollars'] <- paste0('$',my.data.long$value[my.data.long$variable=='sales.dollars'])


datatable((dcast(my.data.long, variable ~ date, value.var = c("value"))))
```